# Python 3.3.4 Cx_Freeze ImportError: DDL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, cmd, cx-freeze

I am attempting to use `cx_Freeze` to turn a `.py` file that I wrote in Python 3.3.4. In running the build command, I get the following error.

```
C:\Python33>c:\python33\python.exe setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    executables=executables
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 930, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 949, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 949, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 234, in run
metadata = metadata)
File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 101, in __init
__
for n in self._GetDefaultBinPathExcludes() + binPathExcludes]
File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 235, in _GetDe
faultBinPathExcludes
import cx_Freeze.util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Have I not installed `cx_freeze` correctly? Or am I running it all wrong?
Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get the correct 32/64 bit version corresponding to your version of Python?

Comment: @ThomasK Yes I have tried both the 64 bit and the 32 bit.

Comment: Having the exact same issue here, running 32-bit python 2.7.9 and cx_Freeze/util.pyd.   Util.pyd is in the cx_Freeze directory and is world-readable.  pip list shows cx-Freeze (4.3.4) I'm running under Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found an answer that works for me.

Turns out there's a bug in cx_Freeze  [4.3.4](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/132/cx_freezeutil-dll-load-failed-the#comment-15957249) and downgrading to 4.3.3 solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the util.pyd file with a tool like Dependency Walker in order to check if the error is a result of missing dependencies. I found that it was trying to load msvcr100.dll from the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 runtime which I did not have installed on my machine. If this is also the source of your error, you can try running the [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) / [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) installer to see if this addresses it (you want to pick the one that matches the architecture of your Python installation not of your OS).