# DLL load failed for pymedia fresh install

Tags: python, import, importerror

I get the following when I try to import pymedia anywhere.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Valerie\Desktop\Sounds\MidiKeyboardTests.py", line 2, in 
    import pymedia.audio.sound as sound
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymedia__init__.py", line 26, in 
    import muxer, audio, video, removable
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I'm using 2.7.9 python and 1.3.7.0 pymedia. This would be a non-issue if winsound playback could be stopped, but it can't be in newer versions of windows so I'm stuck using pymedia.

This is right after I used the recommended install, I let the installer do all of the work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949214/python-3-3-4-cx-freeze-importerror-ddl-load-failed-the-specified-module-could